# Go compiler tricks

Tags: go

I read in a talk that the Go compiler will aggressively remove code that isn't used in the output binary.  The talk which I can't find used this for adding some code useful to testing.  Does anybody have more information on how this works?  Are there talks on advanced testing techniques?

Comment: Have a look here for various talks about Go: http://talks.golang.org/

Comment: Can't answer all those questions, but assigning your result to a global is a way to make sure the code doesn't get optimized away--Dave Cheney covers it at the end of [his post on benchmarking](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Five things that make Go fast](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/07/five-things-that-make-go-fast)
>
> [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/)
>
> Dead Code Elimination
>
> ```
> func Test() bool { return false }
>
> func Expensive() {
>   if Test() {
>       // something expensive
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, although the function Test always returns false,
>   Expensive cannot know that without executing it.
>
> When Test is inlined, we get something like this
>
> ```
> func Expensive() {
>   if false {
>       // something expensive is
>       // now unreachable
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The compiler now knows that the expensive code is unreachable.
>
> Not only does this save the cost of calling Test, it saves compiling
>   or running any of the expensive code that is now unreachable.

---

For example, adding some code useful to testing,

```
func Complicated() {
    if Test() {
        // something for testing
    }
}
```

Switching `Test` from

```
func Test() bool { return false }
```

inlined

```
func Complicated() {
    if false {
        // something for testing
        // unreachable
    }
}
```

to

```
func Test() bool { return true }
```

inlined

```
func Complicated() {
    if true {
        // something for testing
        // reachable
    }
}
```

can be useful to include code just for testing.

Comment: Of course, in practice `const Test = false` is probably a better choice.

Comment: the part I'm missing how do you toggle this for testing without modifying the source?

Comment: @Drew of course you have to modify the source (but just one line). How would the compiler remove anything from the binary if it wasn't at the source level? (I mean, yes, self-modifying binaries exist, but...)

Answer (score 0):

Dave Cheney talks about this in his benchmark blog article:

http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go (A note on compiler optimisations)